# What is the significance of the fox?

Tags: wu-assassins

When Kai pursues McCoulough into (what I think is) the past, the latter reunites with his family. After this, he hears a noise and goes out to investigate. He sees what appears to be a disembowled, bloody fox, and then Kai rushes at him and starts tussling with him. However, it's unclear why there is a dead fox or what its connection with Kai is.

Why is there a dead fox? Did Kai kill it? If so, why?